# DropBox sync on Ubuntu Server stopped working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sync, dropbox

I have the Dropbox linux client installed on a server - and it has been working fine for around a month. But just this week has stopepd syncing some files uploaded from Mac or via the web.

I have checked the status of the client on the server and it all looks OK to me.

```
~/.dropbox/dropbox.py status
Idle
```

The tool output looks fine.

```
sudo service dropbox status
dropboxd for USER ubuntu: running (pid 11306)
```

The service is running.

If I create a file in the ~/Dropbox directory it shows up on the web browser version almost immediately, which is great so I'm 100% sure it's connected to Dropbox.

```
touch /home/ubuntu/Dropbox/testfile.txt
# Check web browser client 5 seconds later, file is there
```

I have tried removing and recreating the ~/Dropbox folder completely, but for some reason some of the files shown in the web broswer, simply do not get copied into the folders on the server. The files are nothing special, just basic .jpg files - with normal names like ABC123.jpg.

Can anyone point me to a place to start trying to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have selective sync configured?

Comment: Same thing happened to me both on desktop and android phone

Comment: If you can't get it working, then I would use AeroFS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to have worked was downloading the folder from dropbox via web - deleting it and then re-creating and uploading it.

Only then would the server see the files and sync them.

So it's not a great solution, but has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a files permission issue, I know Dropbox can sometimes get pernickety with regards to this (and just blanketly set permissions to 777 - which seems like a bit of a security risk, but I digress).

Check if there's any correlation between file permissions and those which will/will not upload.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem may be found here:

[What do I do if Dropbox is stuck syncing, won't launch, or reports an error?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/72)